# Counting triangles in a big triangle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

[A big triangle made up of many smaller triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3bdz.png)

How am I supposed to count the total amount of triangles in this figure?

Comment: The figure is the link

Comment: I presume the figure is poorly drawn and that all lines should converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 cases.  First case, where the large triangle is cut into 3 smaller triangles all touching at the middle.  Each of these small triangles consist of 4 triangles.  Then there would be 10 triangles in each small triangle.  Since there are 3 small triangles, 3 x 10 = 30 triangles.

Case 2, whereby each line cuts the large triangle into 2 triangles.  There are 6 of these lines, so 6 x 2 = 12 triangles.

Total number of triangles would be 12 + 30 + 1(we mustn't forget the big triangle) = 43 triangles in total.

Comment: @Noabji pls upvote too